# Excel: How to negate a boolean array?

Tags: arrays, excel

I want to use "NOT" for arrays. I.e.:

```
"NOT"((True, False, True)) = (False, True, False)
```

I want to use this technique within a sumproduct formula, namely

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($R$2:$R$9000=$W$5:$AF$5)*($S$2:$S$9000))
```

Now, I want to use the negated array and am still looking for an elegant version how to do it. I tried:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(NOT($R$2:$R$9000=$W$5:$AF$5)*($S$2:$S$9000))
```

and

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($R$2:$R$9000<>$W$5:$AF$5)*($S$2:$S$9000))
```

which both did not work out as assumed. I know that I could use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($R$2:$R$9000<>$W$5)*($R$2:$R$9000<>$X$5)*...*($R$2:$R$9000<>$AF$5)*($S$2:$S$9000))
```

But I hope for a more elegant version.

Do you know a more elegant answer?

Many greetings,
Peter

Comment: Have you tried [`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't seem to work either... :-/

Comment: Actually, we're missing the obvious - `=SUM($R$2:$R$9000) -
 SUMPRODUCT(NOT($R$2:$R$9000=$W$5:$AF$5)*($S$2:$S$9000))`, so if you have the total of the R column already, just deduct your product from it.

Comment: Yeah, actually (sum - sumproduct) is how i "fixed" it now. But I needed to perform some other sumproducts on a similar database and needed to think about the algebra multiple time instead of once only...

Comment: Well, I suppose you can `(sum - (sumproduct + sumproduct + ...))` if that's what you mean...  Nice solution for that, by the way - using logic to multiply the values, very elegant. If Microsoft change the value of True anytime soon you're in trouble, but still - good solution!  :o)

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping for a more elegant solution for this myself, but I think this is the best I've figured so far: `--(<bitmask>)=0`.

In your case, `SUMPRODUCT(--(($R$2:$R$9000=$W$5:$AF$5)*($S$2:$S$9000))=0)`, or even `SUMPRODUCT((($R$2:$R$9000=$W$5:$AF$5)*($S$2:$S$9000))=0)` should work since the `*` operator already converts the bitmask to integers.

The idea is to convert the `{TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}` bitmask into integers `{1,0,1}` with the `--`. Then if they're `FALSE` (`0`) the result of the `=0` comparison is `TRUE`. If `TRUE` (`1`), then the result is `FALSE`.

If you use something like `<bitmask>+<bitmask>` to simulate an element-wise `OR`, it should still work because the `TRUE`s (sums) will still be >0.

Does that work for you?

Comment: Hi PKB, I have tried
SUMPRODUCT(--(($R$2:$R$9000=$W$5:$AF$5)*($S$2:$S$9000))=0) which results in 0. I have also tried to fix it via SUMPRODUCT(--(($R$2:$R$9000=$W$5:$AF$5) =0)*($S$2:$S$9000)). But this seems to work only in a simplfied context. namely SUMPRODUCT(--(($R$2:$R$9000=$W$5:$W$5) =0)*($S$2:$S$9000)). Otherwise I am getting more or less a total sum.

Comment: I think the first one fails because the entries of ($S$2:$S$9000) are not in 0 and 1